# Water turbine generator

Tags: circuit-design, generator, induction-motor, power-generation

I have a 5.5 hp 3-phase induction motor, 440 V, 60 Hz, 1760 rpm attached to water turbine wheel that I would like to utilize as line source for home power generation.

May I know the additional circuit tools needed to make it run efficiently and not to overheat? Also, what is the potential power output in kW?

I would appreciate very much if you can include the circuit diagram.

Comment: You'll need to have something set up to convert whatever voltage and frequency it generates (which will vary based on load and water flow) to 60 Hz and 120/240 V. This is not a trivial task.

Comment: Thanks. I am working on my water turbine generator and hopefully it would be finished soon as I get all the necessary information.

Comment: I graduated in mechanical engg and have some difficulty in electrical circuit issues.

Comment: Thanks Neil for your input.

Answer (score 0):

> *May I know the additional circuit tools needed to make it run....*

3 phase induction **motors** work by inducing a voltage onto the rotor winding. The rotor winding is also shorted (as per the squirrel cage motor) and, a large current circulates in the rotor. This sets up a magnetic field that is attracted to the rotating magnetic field produced by the stator. When run as a **generator**, this idea falls flat and, you need to use a power source for the rotor to magnetize it.

Comment: The rotor doesn't need to be powered directly.  Induction motors make fine generators when connected to the grid.

Comment: @Theodore the OP doesn't say anything about connecting it to the grid. They say: *I would like to utilize as line source for home power generation*.

Comment: OP also didn't say they wanted to run only in island mode.

Comment: It will only support or supplement the existing power I have in the house. However, If it would run according to perceive expectation, I will be using it in the farm where there is no existing power supply. Water is not a problem, there's plenty of it. I used the water to irrigate the plants.

Comment: Thank you, Theodore, for your input.

Answer (score 0):

When an induction machine runs as a motor, it spins at a few percent below synchronous speed. This difference is called the 'slip', and is the means by which the effective 'transformer' between stator and rotor sees a net frequency to induce current in the rotor.

When an induction machine is run as a generator, it has to be spun at a few percent faster than the synchronous speed of the voltage source that's providing an AC voltage on its terminals. Then it will deliver a current that can be used.

For a turbine whose speed can vary, this means the AC voltage source you use has to be able to track the turbine rotation speed, and excite it with an appropriate lower frequency. With this frequency variation, it means you cannot directly grid-tie to a grid. If you do want to feed the grid, you'll need to go through a frequency changer. If you want to power any transformer or motor-based appliances, even without a grid tie, you'll need the frequency changer to give them roughly the right frequency.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a 5.5hp 3phase induction motor, 440v, 60hz, 1760rpm attached to
> water turbine wheel that I would like to utilize as line source for
> home power generation.

Will this ever be used when there is no utility electric power source available ("island" mode)?  Or will it only be used to supplement the utility power ("grid-interactive" mode)?

This makes a big difference.

> May I know the additional circuit tools needed to make it run
> efficiently and not to overheat. Also, what is the potential power
> output in KW?

Depending on your approach, the mechanical controls might need to be more sophisticated.  If you want the generator to spin at the right speed to be synchronized with the grid (and deliver power in the right direction rather than run as a motor) you need to control the mechanical power (with actuated valves, nozzles, etc.)

If you omit complicated mechanical controls and allow the generator to spin at whatever speed it runs with the available pressure and flow, you'll need some kind of frequency conversion to deliver power to the grid, or to loads that are sensitive to frequency (especially other induction motors and some clocks.)

> I would appreciate very much if you can include the circuit diagram.

At this power capacity (which isn't even very much) you're probably better off with an off-the-shelf product.  This is partly because of the complexity, and partly because working with mains voltage and interconnecting in a household setting can be quite dangerous, and sometimes in ways that are not obvious.